# Treesitter Fails to Parse Rust Code and Results in Error

Tags: rust, lua, neovim, treesitter

I've been using `NeoVim` for quite a while now, and my config has not changed whatsoever. Recently I ran the command `TSUpdate` simply to update my parsers. `Treesitter` seems to work for other languages such as `python` and `lua`. However when I attempt to use it with `rust`, immediately after typing, an error appears that says:
`treesitter/highlighter: Error executing lua: ...im-win64\share\nvim\runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:259: query: invalid node type at position 617 for language rust stack traceback:`

`[C]: in`

I am using `packer.nvim` to manage plugins, and I did run `PackerSync` to make sure I wasn't using any deprecated resources.

My `treesitter` config can be found at the following link:
https://github.com/kawaleo/kawaleo.nvim/blob/config/lua/configs/local/treesitter.lua